# I'm getting an unhandled error when trying to run node server

Tags: node.js, angular

So, I'm really new to node and I feel like this might be something very simple but I can't figure it out. I installed the dependencies but when I try to start the server by doing "node server" I get this error:

```
Vladimirs-MBP:comeat-server Vladimir$ node server
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 18.194.133.202:3001
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1350:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1517:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:10)
```

Comment: Looks like something may already be using port 3001

Comment: Your `3001` port is already used by some service, please change the porrt

Answer (score 1):

Your `3001 port` is already used by some service, please change the `port`

```
var http = require('http');

//create a server object:
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
  res.end(); 
}).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

You can use **these commands** to check what ports are being used:

```
 1. sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
 2. netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

You can `kill` that `process number` using

`sudo kill -9 process_number`

Comment: I get this when I try to run sudo kill. Vladimirs-MBP:comeat-server Vladimir$ sudo kill -9 3001
kill: 3001: No such process

Comment: It should actually be the process number as opposed to the port number, try the command from the other answer (`sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3001)`) which will go and get the process number of the process on that port

Comment: Ok, it worked but I still get the same error when I "node server"

Comment: Try changing it to a different port and see if that works

Comment: I tried, still the same error. What port should I use tho, how can I find out which ones are available?

Comment: yes its process number, can you please add your code, change the port to something like `3005` and check

Answer (score 0):

Your 3001 port is in use. you should use another port or kill 3001 port and then use it.

for example

```
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3001)
```